# A question on irreducible $R-$ Module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I got difficulty on proving why the isomorphic class of simple $R$-module over, where $R$ is artinian is finite. Can I have your assist?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$R/J(R)$ is a semisimple ring, where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical.

The isotypes of simple $R$ modules are in 1-1 correspondence with the isotypes of simple $R/J(R)$ modules.

A semisimple ring has one isotype of simple module per Wedderburn component. A Wedderburn component is just one of the simple rings in the Wedderburn decomposition of the ring.